# Homogeneity of $f(x,y) = \frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: graphing-functions

Regarding my previous question about the function $f(x,y)$ somebody claimed that $f(ax,ay)=af(x,y)$ is only true for "homogeneous" $x$ and $y$.  Does anyone know what "homogeneous" means in this context?

Comment: A function $f(x,y)$ of two variables is called homogeneous if $f(ax,ay)=a^nf(x,y)$. The notion extends to arbitrary numbers of variables.

Comment: It does not make sense to call the variables homogeneous. But it makes sense to call a *function* homogeneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f(x,y)$ of two variables is called homogeneous if $f(ax,ay)=a^nf(x,y)$

Comment: A function of two variables is "homogeneous of degree n" if f(ax, ay)= a^n f(x, y)".   "somebody claimed that f(ax,ay)=af(x,y) 
 is only true for "homogeneous" x and y".  Are you sure they didn't say "for f homogenous"?  That is the definition of f(x,y) being homogeneous (of degree 1).

.